# FXML, Alternate Uses: Using ObservableList<>

Tags: java, fxml

As in this thread [FXML: Alternate Uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456796/fxml-alternate-uses), I am building an application that uses FXML for loading objects into memory directly.

I have successfully setup objects where specific properties can be easily set like `hostName`, `typeName`, `moto`, e.g. But, in FXML you have lists - like child nodes of JavaFX UI elements held in a `ObservableList`. I am having trouble using a `features` (`ObservableList`) property in FXML. It gives an error that `UnsupportedOperationException: cannot determine type for property`. Why isn't it able to add elements to the list if it can for other objects like `BorderPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ObservableList` has no public concrete types you have to use `FXCollections` factory methods to obtain an instance. Luckily, FXML was designed to handle cases like this: by using the `fx:factory` attribute. You can learn more about the different `fx:` options in [Introduction to FXML | JavaFX 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

An example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>

<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <!-- your children elements -->

</FXCollections>
```

The type of the element will be the type returned by the factory method declared by `fx:factory`. In this case, an `ObservableList` (backed by an `ArrayList`).

---

If you have a class defined with an `ObservableList` field (such as `features`) with an appropriate getter you should be able to do this:

```xml
<YourObject>
    <features>
        <!-- your feature elements -->
    </features>
</YourObject>
```

However, I am having trouble getting that to work. When I tried it only the first element was added to the `ObservableList` and I have no idea why (maybe it's a bug).

I managed to workaround this using:

```xml
<fx:define>
    <ArrayList fx:id="tempList">
        <!--- your feature elements -->
    </ArrayList>
</fx:define>

<YourObject>
    <features>
        <fx:reference source="tempList"/>
    </features>
</YourObject>
```

I was also having issues using the [`DefaultProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/DefaultProperty.html) annotation as well for some reason. It kept telling me "doesn't have a default property"... but it does!

Other than the "workaround" you could simply have it "set" the `ObservableList` just like any other property. Or you could (probably) use an `FXML` annotation in combination with `fx:id`.

Comment: Thank You, sir! Now I can easily build the UI for my school's voting system (I am a student).

Comment: @SukantKumar I didn't post the `.java` file (didn't make one) but I added some information I think better reflects your situation. I don't know why I couldn't just define the FXML the same way I'd define `<children>` with something like a `StackPane`, however.